# Cannot Login it shows Object not found

Tags: codeigniter

admin/views/login.php

```
<?php $this->load->library('form_validation'); ?> <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> <?php echo form_open('cpages/ceklogin'); ?> <div class="login-card"> <center><?php //echo $warning; ?> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('warning'); ?> </center> <h2>Gionda CMS Login</h2><br> <form> <div class="login"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></div> <div class="login"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></div> <br> <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login"> </form> <div class="login-help"> <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a> </div> </div>
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function ceklogin() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
        $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query=$this->db->get('login');
        if ($query->num_rows() >= 1)
             {
                // echo 'LOGIN BERHASIL !';
                $this->load->model('Mpages');
                $data['login']=$this->db->get('login');  
                $data['login']=$this->Mpages->login();
                $this->load->view('index', $data);
             }
        else
            {
                // echo 'LOGIN GAGAL !';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Your username and password are wrong !');
                //$data['warning']='Your username and password are wrong !';
                $this->load->view('login');
            }           
    }
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function login()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

username email password role

user user@mail.com 12345 administrator
user2 user2@mail.com $2y$10$PrDTzzETQ.NzI9eIN0WYDubhBZhkg9XEo10MxRYpv4M manager

I have tried to login with username: user password: 12345 and have not been successful to login yet. I wonder why?

http://localhost/masterlinkci2/cpages/ceklogin

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

I wonder how to route it:

routes.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'cpages/login';
    $route['cpages/login'] = 'cpages/login';
```

Comment: Have you tried any answers don't forget to accept which ones have worked.

Comment: The answer is difficult for me to digest.  or if you have an account in https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/507558/cannot-login it will be easier to see.  I am posting the same question.

Comment: I still can use the same view right?

Comment: All it is an example. One thing I notice is you need to learn where to load the helpers and libraries etc you have loaded form_validation library where it should be loaded on controller As again you need to read properly through here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller I notice you changed your user profile name also on here.

Comment: Where to place:                                                                                       public function validate_password($username, $password) {
    // Get the stored password from DB
    $stored_password = $this->get_this_users_password($username);

    if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

No need to call models method.You can get tables data at your controller.Try like this..

```
public function ceklogin() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query=$this->db->get('login');
        if ($query->num_rows() >= 1)
             {
                // echo 'LOGIN BERHASIL !';
                $data['login']=$query->result();  //returns data in object format
                $this->load->view('index', $data);
             }
        else
            {
                // echo 'LOGIN GAGAL !';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Your username and password are wrong !');
                //$data['warning']='Your username and password are wrong !';
                $this->load->view('login');
            }           
    }
```

In your view get data using `foreach` loop.Like this..

```
foreach($login as $l)
{
echo $l->username."<br/>";
echo $l->password;
so on..
}
```

Comment: I do not get the view part.  I still get the same error appears:  http://localhost/masterlinkci2/cpages/ceklogin  -  Object not found!

Comment: post your `index` view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example how done mine in model

I think your using php hash

Once created hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Then you need to verify it http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

```
 public function validate_password($username, $password) {
    // Get the stored password from DB
    $stored_password = $this->get_this_users_password($username);

    if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I my self I autoload my model but you don't have to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

$autoload['model'] = array('user/user_model');
```

Model

Filename: User_model.php first letter all way only upper case.

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $table_name = 'user';

    private $user_id;
    private $username;
    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $email;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) {

            $this->db->select('user_id, username, firstname, lastname, email, date_joined');
            $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . $this->table_name);
            $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->where('status', '1');
            $user_query = $this->db->get();

            if ($user_query->num_rows() == 1) {

                $this->user_id = $user_query->row()->user_id;
                $this->username = $user_query->row()->username;
                $this->firstname = $user_query->row()->firstname;
                $this->lastname = $user_query->row()->lastname;
                $this->email = $user_query->row()->email;
            }

        } else {
            $this->logout();
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);

        $this->user_id = '';
        $this->username = '';
        $this->firstname = '';
        $this->lastname = '';
        $this->email = '';
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        if ($this->validate_password($username, $password)) {
            $this->db->select('user_id, username, firstname, lastname, email, date_joined');
            $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . $this->table_name);
            $user_query = $this->db->get();

            if ($user_query->num_rows() == 1) {

                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_query->row()->user_id);

                $this->user_id = $user_query->row()->user_id;
                $this->username = $user_query->row()->username;
                $this->firstname = $user_query->row()->firstname;
                $this->lastname = $user_query->row()->lastname;
                $this->email = $user_query->row()->email;

                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
    } 

    public function validate_password($username, $password) {
        $stored_password = $this->get_this_users_password($username);

        if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function get_this_users_password($username) {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . $this->table_name);

        return $query->row()->password;
    }

    public function get_this_users_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    public function get_this_users_username() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function get_this_users_firstname() {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function get_this_users_lastname() {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function get_this_users_email() {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Controller function example

> You load libraries and helpers etc on controller not on view,

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user/user_model');
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

       // login view

    } else {

       $login = $this->user_model->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));

       if ($login == true) {
           redirect('some-controller');
       } else {
           set a error or reload login view.
       }
    }
}
```